# How to find resisting moment with rebars of different yield strengths?

Tags: reinforced-concrete

When designing a concrete slab or rectangular beam, how would you compute the Mn value if there were two rows of rebars one with a yield strenght of 40 ksi and the other with the yield strenght at 60 ksi?

Comment: Build yourself a spreadsheet with all the varying parameters according to the code you use, then seeing the effects should be just a matter of "correcting" given values.

Answer (score 1):

I won't bother with the actual calculations since those depend on the codes and methods you're using. I'll just focus on the philosophy of how to do it, which is the same in every case.

When calculating $M_n$ in the standard case, you determine a centroid which represents your rebar. If all your rows have the same number of bars and equal vertical spacing between rows, this is trivial to determine, with the centroid located at the average height of all the rows.

In this case, however, you need to calculate the adjusted centroid considering the effect of the different yield stresses for each row. You do this by finding the lowest yield stress (in this case, 40 ksi) and then, for each row, calculating a ratio between the row's yield stress and that minimum stress. In this case, the ratios would be 1 and 1.5 for the 40 ksi and 60 ksi rows, respectively.

You then pretend that all the rows have 40 ksi steel, but adjust the steel area of each row by that factor. So you're basically pretending that instead of bars of equal diameter but different steels, that the bars are made of the same steel (40 ksi), but one of them uses bars with 50% more area. When calculating the rebar's centroid, this will effectively move it towards the stronger steel.

When you then calculate the necessary steel area, do so using that minimal yield strength (40 ksi), and then adjust the necessary area for the stronger steel row by the inverse factor (divide by 1.5, in this case).

Obviously, this solution assumes similar behavior between the two steels (i.e. same Young's Modulus, etc), and that the codes don't specify anything different.